# Scala: using folding to generate a list of Int's

Tags: scala, folding

I'm learning Scala, and as an assignment I have to use folding to generate a list of Int's:

```
// Generate list of integers by applying f to b until it returns None
def unfold(b: Int, f: Int => Option[(Int, Int)]): IntList = {
  f(b) match {
    case None => Nil()
    case Some((x, y)) => Cons(x,unfold(y, f))
  }
}
```

This unfold is working just fine, but now I have to write a fromUntil, and honestly I'm completely lost with what to do?? So I just started randomly, but this isn't working at all. Some help would be appreciated!

```
// generate the list of integers from i until j
def fromUntil(i: Int, j: Int): IntList = {
    unfold(i, (x: Int) =>if(x < j) Some((j, j - 1)) else None)
    }
}
```

Jerome

Answer (score 1):

As it's an homework, I don't give you a complete answer but only some clues:

1. The hardest part of your work is to define what must be the `f` function in `fromUntil`
2. look at how unfold is implemented. Especially the non-terminating case. Where does that `y`came from, when was it computed?
3. Can you define `f` from what you have oserved?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track:

1. Check that `fromUntil` is syntactically correct - you have some extra braces
2. Because it's "from until" the sequence should keep increasing.
3. `y` within `unfold` should keep growing with each call

Keep going, try to see what happens if you call `fromUntil(1,1)`, then what happens if you call `fromUntil(1,2)` and so on. You're almost there.